# Demonstrate uniform continuous distribution using tangible items?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

What is the best way to explain "equally likely" in continuous uniform distribution to an audience using tangible or everyday items?

Comment: Tangible bingo globs flood the pavement.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this question is down-voted.  It seems like a perfectly reasonable question to ask.

The simplest thing I can think of is some kind of spinner with a pointer.  Start the spinner and wait until it comes to a stop.  The pointer then indicates the selected point on the spinner's rim. Not only is that point uniformly distributed on the spinner's rim (assuming an ideal spinner), but it should be obvious that it's uniformly distributed.

To make it even clearer, you might contrast it with a continuous distribution that is *not* uniform.  If you can subtly weight a second spinner (imagine both are mounted on a vertical board, for display), you should be able to convince observers that the second spinner will be biased toward one portion of the rim.

ETA: I put in a compensating upvote.